# Git : merging to master branch , add files or pull?

Tags: git, git-branch

**Hello**

I am working my codes in Git.
I made an extra branch to work on and I finished my job. Meanwhile, on the master branch new stuff gets added to it.

If I want to keep my work and get the "new stuff" in my branch, It is better to just add the files that I worked on to the master branch or merge my branch to master? After that I just get to do a git pull to have everything together?

Alternative: How I pull only the new or edited files from master branch into my branch without losing any of my work? 
Which way is better? I don't want to lose the work in my branch, but I really need to update rest of the code from the master branch to able to keep working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pull the changes of `master` branch into your local branch. Then you can create a pull request & merge your branch with master later.

```
$ git branch                 # show your current branch (* before branch-name)
$ git commit -am <message>   # add & commit your local changes
$ git pull origin master     # pull master into your branch
```

Comment: what do you mean to by create a pull request later?  If I pull origin Master, my edited files and code are still there or it will get overwritten by the origin master ?

Comment: "pull request later", I mean you can give your changes to master later. And you already committed your changes when pulling master. So, after pulling you've master's latest codes + you changes.

Answer (score 0):

This [blog](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) may be helpful. It described a very clear git branching work flow.

Answer (score 0):

### You can rebase!

If you want your changes to dominate and be on top of new things rebase is your tool.

```
$ git rebase master
```

Do the above comand in your branch. Then git will rewind your changes, pull the master branch and redo your commits on top!

#### Just don't forget to do a fetch/pull!

```
$ git checkout master
$ git pull
```